# Highcharts navigator padding generating new tick

Tags: javascript, highcharts, navigator

after enabling the navigator on my column chart I have realized that both extremes on the X Axis are being trimmed.

I applied some kind of padding using the event afterSetExtremes but since the data range is dynamic sometimes I end up with new ticks labeled as -1 or 30 for example.

I have created a jsfiddle describing the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/aabreuglez/hzu4twjg/11/

```
events: {
     afterSetExtremes: function (e) {
                    const length = (e.max - e.min) || 1;
                    const minPadding = 0.02;
                    const maxPadding = 0.02;

                    if (e.min === this.chart.xAxis[0].dataMin || e.max === this.chart.xAxis[0].dataMax) {
                        if (e.min === this.chart.xAxis[0].dataMin) {
                            e.min -= length * minPadding;
                        }
                        if (e.max === this.chart.xAxis[0].dataMax) {
                            e.max += length * maxPadding;
                        }
                        this.setExtremes(e.min, e.max);
                    }
                }
            },
```

(If you make zoom a move the axis to the extremes you can find empty columns)

Could I lock the navigator range between a minimum and maximum value avoiding the scrollbar to pass those extremes?

[image]

Comment: You say _I have created a jsfiddle describing the problem._ . No jsfiddle live demo

Comment: I forgot to paste the link! I edited it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set `minPadding` and `maxPadding` for the navigator's axis. The trick here is that it needs to be done by updating the already rendered axis (in `chart.events.load`) instead of providing options (`navigator.xAxis` - it's not gonna work).

`minPadding` and `maxPadding` are fractions - maybe you'll be able to find a proper values for them and this issue won't happen.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/x6xu2y3j/

```
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      events: {
        load: function() {              
          this.navigator.xAxis.update({
            minPadding: 0.007,
            maxPadding: 0.007
          });
        }
      }
    },
```

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.minPadding
- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.maxPadding
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, the problem is that my range isn't fixed in all the charts. I'm currently tracking https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1172 where the option pointRange = null seems to solve the problem but generates and extra column at the beginning depending on the zoom (even if I force the starOnTick to false).